# Spyder with python3 crashes after upgrading ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.10)

Tags: spyder

After updating Ubuntu from 14 to 16.10, I cannot anymore use my spyder editor. I also have anaconda2 and anaconda3, and since I'm with ubuntu16.10, spyder3 (anaconda3/bin/spyder3) crashes. 
Here is the message:

> /home/cecile/anaconda3/bin/python: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol:
>   FcWeightFromOpenType

I think it comes from QtWebkit, but not sure.

Do you have any idea ? It was all OK when I was under ubuntu 14 :(

Thanks for your help.

Cécile

Answer (score 0):

To fix the Anaconda error, please run

```
conda install pango
```

The Ubuntu error will be fixed in **17.04** with a new version of Spyder.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks a lot. I previously installed anaconda4, then ran your comand. Now, everything is perfect !